# Question about Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability

A box contains $2$ coins and $p_i (I = 1, 2)$ denotes the probability of a head
when the $I^{th}$ coin is tossed. Suppose $p_1 = 1/4, p_2 = 1/2$

a) Suppose that one coin is selected at random from the box and when it is tossed three
times, two head are obtained. Work out the probability that it is the $I^{th}$  coin that has been selected $(I = 1, 2).$

b) If a tail has been obtained on the first toss of the selected coin and the same coin is tossed again, what would be the probability of obtaining a head this time?

Comment: Have you tried to apply Bayes' theorem? Where did you get stuck? The probability of picking a specific coin is just $1/2$ and then you know the probability of heads for both of them.

Comment: well I just learned about it but the teacher decided to give a suprise online test so i dont even know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...the teacher decided to give a suprise online test so i dont even know where to start

The exercise is a standard application of Bayes' theorem

a)

$$\mathbb{P}[2H]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}\cdot\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^2\cdot\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}\cdot\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^3=A+B$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[1^{st}|2H]=\frac{A}{A+B}=\frac{3}{11}$$

b) I think you can try to solve it with similar reasoning

Comment: thanks so much brother